# Why does MikTex TeXworks fail to convert a latex document to .pdf?

Tags: pdf, conversion, latex, miktex

I've created a basic Latex document based on an example I found online:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
Field Name:&FIRST_FIELD
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}
Field Name:&SECOND_FIELD
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I installed the latest version of MikTex for Windows but every time I run it and select 'pdfLatex' from the drop-down and hit the green play button I get this message:

> Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>
> C:/Users/jonc/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
>
> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
>   need help.
>
> Sorry, but C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-pdftex.exe did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
>
> C:/Users/jonc/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log
>
> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
>   need help.

That first log suggests there's a permissions error but I've not idea what file it has a problem with:

```
2015-10-14 11:01:23,455+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-14 11:01:23,472+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-14 11:01:23,472+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-14 11:01:23,473+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-14 11:01:23,489+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2015-10-14 11:01:25,303+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-14 11:01:25,320+0100 INFO  initexmf - Making format links...
2015-10-14 11:01:25,357+0100 INFO  initexmf - Making script links...
2015-10-14 11:01:25,484+0100 INFO  initexmf -   C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-taskbar-icon.exe
2015-10-14 11:01:25,488+0100 INFO  initexmf -   C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-update.exe
2015-10-14 11:01:25,582+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-14 11:01:25,597+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2015-10-14 11:01:25,618+0100 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --verbose --admin
2015-10-14 11:01:56,061+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-14 11:01:56,093+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2015-10-14 11:01:56,093+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\4d5868e95e95ecff33e8315a05cb58f3.fndb
2015-10-14 11:01:56,093+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-10-14 11:01:56,093+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-10-14 11:01:56,242+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-14 11:01:56,274+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2015-10-14 11:01:56,274+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\4d5868e95e95ecff33e8315a05cb58f3.fndb
2015-10-14 11:01:56,274+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-10-14 11:01:56,274+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-10-14 11:02:07,626+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-14 11:02:07,659+0100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2015-10-14 11:02:07,659+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\jonc\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\4d5868e95e95ecff33e8315a05cb58f3.fndb
2015-10-14 11:02:07,659+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-10-14 11:02:07,659+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This might also be considered a TEX question and related to this:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471842/110394 

Thanks to your answer, I was able to resolve my issues.

Comment: Also related on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/miktex-users/thread/CAEErVS6BtEadcjjXeEoW0-XCAs02EsaOYuckXPGQ22mDi7shrQ%40mail.gmail.com/#msg34520122 (permalink to just the question: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/mailman/message/34520122/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this up and running by repeatedly running `MiKTeX Update (Admin)` from the start menu. I think when I first did that, the update software found a distributor which it couldn't update for and then failed quietly.

The trick is to keep running update until there are no packages listed as needing to be updated.